# Is this data really detrended?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I have a time-series vector for a macroeconomic indicator, which clearly has trends, when I apply the `detrend` method of matlab, I see a change in the autocorrelation plot, but I suspect it's still not really decorrelated.

This is the original acf plot:
[image]

and this is the plot after `detrend` :
[image]

the autocorrelation definitely decreased for bigger lags, but still most of them are in the reject region, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something correct.

AFAIK, the `detrend` method computes the linear trend with simple least-squares fitting, and subtracts the trend from each data point. so maybe I need a more advanced detrending method. can I use PCA for this purpose, or any other alternatives?

In the end, I want to obtain a measure of how the value changed with respect to last time point (month), so I'm actually expecting big autocorrelation values in lags 12, 24 etc.

Thanks for any help!

### Edit

The data I'm using is a time-series vector for a macroeconomic indicator, namely the consumer price index. It is monthly data which starts at January 1990. Here is the link for the data: http://pastebin.com/e31TahHj

Comment: Simple methods are often simply wrong as assumptions are made about the nature of the data. For example if the observed series has level shifts detrending is useless. Please post your original data in a column oriented excel file  and I will try and form an answer for you. Include info regarding what kind of data it is, frequency of measurement and start date.

Comment: The ACF is of little use in testing trends.

Comment: I wouldn't use an ACF to try to decide this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autocorrelated series show exponential decay in ACF. The second ACF falls into this pattern pretty clearly. So, it may belong to AR(p) process $$x_t=c+\sum_{i=1}^p\theta_ix_{t-i}+e_t$$

On the other hand, the first ACF doesn't look like exponential decay. It could belong to many kind of processes, including MA(q) process, such as 
$$x_t=c+e_t+\sum_{i=1}^q\phi_ie_{t-i}$$

In fact, the first ACF may also be ARMA(p,q), you don't have PACF plot to get a better idea of the lag structure of the process.

Note, how I'm avoiding the discussion of time or other trends, because even without trends pure ARIMA(p,d,q) can generate both of your ACF plots. Hence, ACF plots are not the good tool to study trends. Actually, it's hard to tell the trend from autocorrelation from differences in short series in practice.

UPDATE

On an economic side, CPI is usually considered to be exponentially growing series. So, you better take the log of CPI before detrending it with MATLAB `detrend` function, because this guy is for linear trends only. Also, economists usually work with inflation rather than CPI, which is either simple or continuous growth rate of CPI. Unless you use CPI to deflate assets or output.

For instance, here's the CPI of energy cost in Canada. It looks exponentially growing, generally, but with periods of deflation.

[image]

It looks nothing like a nice linear or even smooth exponential though. It's quite rough, which can be seen better on the plot with inflation/deflation that follows next.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'm still very "noob" in time-series processing, so I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. Maybe I need decorrelation (or are they the same thing?). And do you propose any approach, or is taking the log and detrending a sound way to preprocess the data? Thanks,

Comment: You had a specific question, which was probably answered now. You may want to post a different question at this time, on detrending. Just be careful not to make it too general, specific questions have better chance to get answered, in my opinion. With CPI in mind you are getting into econometrics area, which has its own domain specifics compared to plain statistics. There's a lot of literature on building indices by the way

Comment: You are right, I accepted your answer. But I'm still not sure what question should I be asking :) so any further help appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: It seems to me your question is how to prepare CPI series before adding them to the index you are building. You may also have a question on how to build macro indices. You know better what is in your mind

Comment: I actually created a very basic pipeline (I discretize the change values into C classes, then I try to do K-steps-ahead forecasting by using multiple input variables and their lagged values), and I'm looking for ways to improve it. I normalize the data beforehand, so each change is a small number (since the whole data is btw. 0 and 1). Now I'm looking for new ways to improve it, well, hopefully to a level comparable to state-of-the-art approaches :)